# Redirect standard error of one command to standard input of another command

Tags: io-redirection, stdin

I wish to redirect standard error of one command to standard input of another command like

```
g++ filename.cpp 'redirection' less
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pipe to do that

```
command1 2>&1 >/dev/null | command2
```

It will redirect the standard error stream of the first command to the standard input stream of the second command while discarding the standard output stream of `command1`.

The redirections are done in order:

1. `command1 2>&1` will redirect file descriptor 2 (standard error) to wherever file descriptor 1 (standard output) is connected.
2. `>/dev/null` (the same as `1>/dev/null`) will redirect standard output to `/dev/null`.

In your case:

```
g++ filename.cpp 2>&1 >/dev/null | less
```

Comment: Is there a way to shorten "2>&1 >/dev/null" to something which can be typed shortly 
I tried alias but it didn't work out .